# app not installed as package conflicts with an existing package

Tags: installation, apk

Hello I'm trying to install a game in my android phone from an apk file when i click on install on the place of "install" it's "updatde" then, it shows this message : "app not installed as package conflicts with an existing package" btw the app is not installed on my phone